# Tab Group Confusion – How do I leave Tabs like I found them?

Tags: safari, monterey, tabs

I'm confused about **Tab Groups**, the new feature of Monterey. When I go to a tab group, I'm generally going to open up the home page of a website (which is what I desire & how I set it up).

But if I go to a *different web page* on a particular tab, or add another tab, then when I leave the group, the tab group is changed to show *the last state of the tabs I was using*, and any other tabs I'd added which don't necessarily reflect the tab group!

The next time I go to the group, I won't be going to the home page (which would be my preference). How to I open up a tab group and work with the tabs without changing how the tab group opens the next time??

Answer (score 2):

**Use bookmarks instead**.

Tab groups are intended to help keep different browsing sessions organized; for example, to keep your cooking tabs separate from your school tabs. They keep state because they are simply 'containers' within the main browser.

Bookmarks, on the other hand, allow you to keep a set of tabs in the same state that you saved them. You can easily open a whole folder of bookmarks at once by clicking "open in new tabs" from the bookmarks menu.

[image: menu showing two bookmarks, three folders, and an 'open in new tabs' option]